# Method in jpa - repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a method in ProjectVariantRepository that returns a project variant  based on id. My problem is when I do

```
ProjectVariant projectVariant = projectVariantService.findProjectVariantById(projectVariantId);
        System.out.println("Project Variant: " + projectVariant);
```

my project Variant is null, but in database I have a projectVariantId = 1;

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectVariantRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectVariant, Integer> {
    public ProjectVariant findByProjectVariantId(int projectVariantId);
```

service interface

```
  public interface  ProjectVariantService {
    ProjectVariant findProjectVariantById(int projectVariantId);
```

service implementation

```
@Service
public class ProjectVariantServiceImpl implements ProjectVariantService {

    @Autowired
    private final ProjectVariantRepository projectVariantRepository;


    public ProjectVariantServiceImpl(ProjectVariantRepository projectVariantRepository) {
        this.projectVariantRepository = projectVariantRepository;

    }

    @Override
    public ProjectVariant findProjectVariantById(int projectVariantId) {
        return projectVariantRepository.findByProjectVariantId(projectVariantId);
    }
  }
```

I don't understand what I did wrong..

Comment: Did you check the query printed on console when your service runs?

Comment: Not sure but I think that your query method on the `ProjectVariantRepository` must be `findById(int)` which is already in the repository interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

Comment: I tried to do findById() but it doesn't work.

Comment: in your service change `projectVariantRepository.findByProjectVariantId(projectVariantId);` to `projectVariantRepository.getOne(projectVariantId);` and let me know it works or not

Comment: Do you have a matching `id` field in your `ProjectVariant` entity ? As suggested by @Spara, did you enable and check the query in the logs ?

Comment: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

Add it to application.properties and show debug log

Comment: Thank you for advices, and it works with .getOne().  :)

Comment: I provided as an answer for your question

Comment: Nope, these XXXRepository classes and associated methods are NOTHING at all to do with the JPA API. That is SPRING. Please tag your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `T getOne(ID id);` which is provided by Jpa Repository that returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier;

So In your service you can use this:

```
@Override
public ProjectVariant findProjectVariantById(int projectVariantId) {
    return projectVariantRepository.getOne(projectVariantId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how is the property name in entity class? Id or projectVariantId? If it is Id, you should create you method like:

@Repository
public interface ProjectVariantRepository extends JpaRepository {
    public ProjectVariant findById(int projectVariantId);